# Android ListView onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which has data from a parsed JSON. So this is my sample code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    /**
     * parsing JSON...
     * ...
     * ...
     * ...
     */

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.s_layout, new String[]{NAME, TEXT}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.text});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){


            String inName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String inText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StaffProfileActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("staff_name", inName);
            intent.putExtra("staff_desc", inText);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```

My problem is that how can i pass my data to Intent without using

```
String inName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
```

I mean, how to get my data from my ListView and give it to intent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`adapter.get(position)` will return you a `HashMap<String, String>` for selected element.
And use `List<T>` definition instead of `ArrayList<T>`

Comment: is using this one okay too? 
    Object ob = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

> public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view,
>   int position, long id)
>
> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
>   been clicked. Implementers can **call getItemAtPosition(position) if
>   they need to access the data associated with the selected item.**

so in onItemClick you can retrieve your element :

```
  HashMap<String, String> elt = myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

and then get inName and inText values from elt.